# PHP extension "curl" must be loaded persists even after enabling it

Tags: php, magento, wamp, php-curl

Even after enabling the PHP curl extention in WAMP>PHP>PHP extentions, i get the same error while installing magento !

the error also occurred for SOAP, but it was cleared when i enabled the extention. its not working with CURL ! what i must do ?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: The error message is --> PHP extension "curl" must be loaded

Comment: Since it's WAMP, did you restart the apache after enabling the extension?

Comment: yes i did ! but the error still persists. i've done the same step to enable SOAP,that worked. but with curl its not working

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you using and is it 32bit or 64bit

Answer (score 0):

`php_curl` often also requires the use of `php_openssl` so if you activate the `php_openssl` extension as well in the same way, using the WAMPServer menus you might find that Magento will validate `php_curl`'s existance.